# Spring @autowired annotation with java TimerTask doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, autowired, timertask

autowired annotation doesn't work in java timer task. Please find my code and give solutions.

```
public class MailScheduleTimer extends TimerTask{
    @Autowired
    MailService mailService;

    @Autowired
    UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository;

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MailScheduleTimer.class);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            List<UserAccount> userAccounts = userAccountRepository
                    .getUserAccounts();
            for (UserAccount userAccount : userAccounts) {
                if (userAccount.getUserRole().getName()
                        .equals(RolesConstant.USER_ROLE)
                        && userAccount.getMailStatus().equals("N")) {
                    mailService.sendMail(userAccount.getName(),
                            userAccount.getUserId(), "profile",
                            userAccount.getName());
                    userAccount.setMailStatus("Y");
                    userAccountRepository.saveAndFlush(userAccount);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Unable to Send Mail..." + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your MailScheduleTimer is configured as a bean?

Comment: Show us where you're creating the task object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who should call the run method?  May be you need to annotate it with [@PostConstruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) or implement the [InitializingBean interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html)

By the way. Keep the @Component tag and the package-scan they told you in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your spring beans configuration file

```
<context:component-scan basePackage="Your base package name"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your MailScheduleTimer a bean by adding @Component to the MailScheduleTimer class:

```
@Component
    public class MailScheduleTimer extends TimerTask{

    @Autowired
    MailService mailService;

    @Autowired
    UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository;

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MailScheduleTimer.class);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            List<UserAccount> userAccounts = userAccountRepository
                    .getUserAccounts();
            for (UserAccount userAccount : userAccounts) {
                if (userAccount.getUserRole().getName()
                        .equals(RolesConstant.USER_ROLE)
                        && userAccount.getMailStatus().equals("N")) {
                    mailService.sendMail(userAccount.getName(),
                            userAccount.getUserId(), "profile",
                            userAccount.getName());
                    userAccount.setMailStatus("Y");
                    userAccountRepository.saveAndFlush(userAccount);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Unable to Send Mail..." + e);
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: how do you configure your beans in your application? can you share the appContext.xml file?

Comment: <bean id="mailSchedulerTimer"
 class="com.convergent.profilemgr.scheduler.MailScheduleTimer">
</bean>

 <bean id="scheduledTimerTask" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask">
  <!-- run every 10 secs <property name="period" value="10000"></property> -->
  <property name="timerTask" ref="mailSchedulerTimer"></property>
 </bean>
 <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.TimerFactoryBean">
  <property name="scheduledTimerTasks">
   <list>
    <ref local="scheduledTimerTask"></ref>
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>

Comment: Follow @Naveen advise from the other answer and you should be fine